# Why doesn't my AutoIt script process its command line argument?

Tags: autoit

I want to send a variable to the edit control of a GUI using AutoIt. How can I run my AutoIt script from command line or using shellexecute so it correctly processes its command line parameters?

I am using the below syntax in my AutoIt script:

```
Send("2{TAB}$CmdLine[1]")
```

And the below command to run the compiled AU3 script:

```
tstScript.exe 888
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44339495/4157124).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work if you concatenate the commandline parameter with the send String as follows:

```
Send("2{TAB}" & $CmdLine[1])
```